# Does such an encryption/cipher method exist?

Tags: lua, cryptography

while thinking of an idea to create an encryption/cipher method, I thought of one that I wondered existed already. The method I imagined was to have pre-set characters, but instead, randomly generate meanings for these characters.
Here's what I mean: (Representation in Lua)

```
local Keys = {'a','b','c',} -- Rest of table removed for simplicity
for i,v in pairs(Keys) do 
   Keys[v] = ''
   repeat
        if Key[v] then
            Keys[v] = Keys .. string.char(math.random(1,255))
        else
            Keys[v] = string.char(math.random(1,255))
        end
   until string.len(Keys[v]) == 4
end

print(Keys) --> {'a' = "ą�vź",..}
```

Then when you make a string and transcribe it with the `Keys` table, it'll come out as the meaning given to it. Pretty simple, could probably do more with it, but does something like this already exist (have an official name for the method, perhaps?)

Comment: This seems pretty outstanding, the encryption is based on random numbers. What is the algorithm for decryption? How the program to decrypt is going to randomly find back the original keys?

Comment: I would suggest to stick on standard encryption/cipher algorithms.

Comment: For information, this seems close to `Caesar Cipher` with is one of the earliest encryption methods.

Comment: There are statistical test suites for testing (pseudo) random number generators. Minimum requirement for cipher: encrypted text should pass same statistical tests as output of random number generators. Example of test suit https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf
your cipher will fail "Frequency test within a block" for obvious reasons.

Comment: This is a [*word-based Substitution Cipher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher), generating four-byte words as a "dictionary" to encrypt with.

Comment: Note that not only does this seem to be impossible to decrypt, (and so is not a cipher) it's generating a corrupted output. The `�` character isn't a real character, and doesn't represent a specific byte sequence. It means "this byte sequence is not valid UTF-8." (You can't just take random values between 1 and 255 and interpret them as UTF-8.)

Answer (score 0):

Passwordless obfuscating is also done with [ROT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13).
Just for fun i do this...

```
-- rot.lua
-- Usage: Creates a table (i.e. rot) for using it with string.gsub('Hello World','(.)',rot)
-- A '.' in gsub() is neccessary to hit every single char in a string
-- ROT13 for chars, ROT5 for numbers, ROT8/ROT3/ROT2/ROT1 for signs
-- IMPORTANT: Both key/value pairs has to be datatype string
local args={...}

local rotator=function(...)
local args, rot, c ={...}, {}, ''
-- ROT5 for numbers
for i=48,52 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i+5) end
for i=53,57 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i-5) end
-- ROT13 for chars (upper and lower case)
-- Uppercase letters (ROT13)
for i=65,77 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i+13) end
for i=78,90 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i-13) end
-- Lowercase letters (ROT13)
for i=97,109 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i+13) end
for i=110,122 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i-13) end
-- Signs (ROT8)
for i=32,39 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i+8) end
for i=40,47 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i-8) end
-- Signs (ROT3)
for i=58,60 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i+3) end
for i=61,63 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i-3) end
-- Signs (ROT2)
for i=91,92 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i+2) end
for i=93,94 do rot[c.char(i)]=c.char(i-2) end
-- Sign @ and tabstop (ROT1)
rot['\t']='@'
rot['@']='\t'
return args[1]:gsub('.',rot),rot
end

local _,rot=rotator('koyaanisqatsi') -- Extracting the rot table from function rotator
if #args==2 and args[2]==':preload:' then
 table.insert(rot,rotator)
 return rot
else
 return rotator
end -- Conditional return when required and package.preload is triggered
```

If required und furthermore in `string` table as: `string.rot` you can obfuscating and deobfuscating with the same function...

```
> myvar='koyaanisqatsi'
> print(myvar)
koyaanisqatsi
> myvar=myvar:rot()
> print(myvar)
xblnnavfdngfv
> myvar=myvar:rot()
> print(myvar)
koyaanisqatsi
```